# Superscript number citations in Org?

Tags: org-mode

Is there anyway that I can create citations with superscript numbers?<sup>[1](https://guides.lib.uw.edu/c.php?g=99161&p=642357),[2](https://example.com)</sup>

---

1: https://guides.lib.uw.edu/c.php?g=99161&p=642357

2: https://example.com

---

And if outputting to a format with multiple pages (LaTeX) can the numbers reset each page?<sup>[1](https://example.com)</sup>

---

1: https://example.com

---

And as seen above, have a horizontal rule before the citations start?

The reasoning behind this is so that text formats that don't have links don't get cluttered up with links in-text, but formats that do have links can just jump straight to the link.

Comment: I think this question is slightly more appropriate at the LaTeX exchange than here. You can achieve these things by tweaking your LaTeX headers and environments. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79591/superscripts-in-bibliography-with-bibtex), for example.

Comment: @dangom My goal is to have something in Org that works the way I want in both HTML, LaTeX, and ODT.

Comment: Then you’ll have to add css to your html. Or use a pandoc solution via latex to odt. There is no built in org toggles to do all these things you want, because they are unrelated to the org export. You are asking for aesthetical changes. The org export deals with syntax changes.

Comment: @dangom So there's nothing in Org for citations? :/ Ok.

Comment: Just look at the LaTeX thread I linked above. Just copy paste it with #+latex_header: derivatives and you have what you want. Research a bit around and it'll work.